# add record with api adds an empty record

Tags: php

Currently I am troubleshooting with adding records via an API of Versio. I don't see the problem because the only thing I do is setting a link to the file that creates the record and send it back. Just like so:

```html
<a href="add.record.php?domain=<?php echo $domain ?>&tld=<?php echo $tld ?>">Record toevoegen</a>
```

```html
<?php
require_once("classes/versio.class.php");

$domain = $_GET['domain'];
$tld = $_GET['tld'];

unset($command);
$command = array(
    "command" => "DomainsDNSAddRecord",
    "domain" => $domain,
    "tld" => $tld,
    "name" => "test123.nl",
    "type" => "A",
    "value" => "0.0.0.0",
    "prio" => "10",
    "ttl" => "14400"
);

$api = new Versio_api();
$versio = $api->api_send($command);

if($versio['success']==0) {
    echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
} else {
    header ("location: records.php?domain=$domain&tld=$tld");
}
?>
```

This adds an record with these values, but also adds an empty record which cannot be seen in official Versio data.